# Can "because of" be shortened to "cuz of"?

Tags: informal-language

As we know "because" is often shortened as "cuz" in informal speech. Now I hear "because of" many times a day, so it came to my mind whether I can shorten "because of" to "cuz of".

Comment: "Cuz" is rarely written, except perhaps in texts.   If your're going to shorten it that much, then no need to include the "of", *cuz* how it takes longer to write.  You might as well abbreviate as much as you can.   However, in texts if I don't feel like writing the full word I just use **bc** for "because".

Comment: @Andrew - The OP might be talking about speech, not written English.

Comment: @J.R.  Ah.  Well, in that case there is no way to answer that doesn't depend on dialect and personal preference.   As you know there are many dialects that routinely drop various parts of speech, or rearrange the common order of certain words.

Comment: @Andrew - To me, the OP's query seems like a perfectly reasonable question for an English learner to ask native English speakers. It's the sort of thing ELL was designed to answer, even if the answer might be "it depends".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. Some native speakers do say "'cause of" in place of "because of" when speaking quickly or rushing. It is done without thinking.

However if you need to ask the question, then you are thinking about your speaking. Native speakers don't use "cuz" when trying to speak clearly. If you find yourself naturally reducing "because of" to "cuzov" naturally, that is fine.  But it should not be done artificially or it will sound odd.

You should never use "cuz" in writing, unless you are writing a story and want to show how a character speaks. Never use "cuz" for writing your own words.

Comment: We'll sometimes see _cuz_ written into song lyrics, cuz it's often convenient to use a one-syllable _cuz_ (sometimes written as _cause_, and sometimes using an apostrophe: _'cause_) instead of a two-syllable _because_. Pink's hit "Cuz I Can" comes to mind, as does this [Chris Hawkey lyric](https://chrishawkey.com/track/828330/got-me-this-far): _You don't throw away a diamond just because it's got some dust on /
Trade in a classic cuz it's got a little rust_.

Comment: I would say it's also fine when *texting*, although there are other options.